# How can I extract the FreeBSD major version from freebsd-version (or uname)?

Tags: freebsd

Somtimes you need to manually download a freebsd package (organized by major version) and want to write a script to get it, is there a way to extract the Freebsd major version using `freebsd-version` and `sed`?

Comment: Why don't you use `pkg fetch`? For example `pkg fetch -Uy -o ~/ firefox` will download the firefox package to your home directory.

Comment: @uzsolt : This was on a freenas (aka truenas) system where freebsd ports repo by default is disabled (and I don't feel like enabling it). Not something one would normally do but this was a core-level non-jail package that was needed.

Answer (score 1):

Optionally, [*cut*](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?cut) the string

```bsh
shell> uname -r
13.0-RELEASE
shell> export FREEBSD_MAJOR_VERSION=`uname -r | cut -d . -f 1`
shell> echo $FREEBSD_MAJOR_VERSION
13
```

Answer (score 0):

considering the format of the version from `freebsd-version` is something like `12.2-RELEASE-p14` , with `sed` one could select and replace (`s/`) the area including and after the first period (`\..*`) and replace it with null (`//`) :

```
FREEBSD_MAJOR_VERSION=`freebsd-version | sed 's/\..*//'`
```

you can then use it in a script for, say, downloading a package...

```
wget http://pkg.freebsd.org/freebsd:${FREEBSD_MAJOR_VERSION}:x86:64/[...rest of url...]
```